# Wireless Broadcom issue on Mac Mini 2012

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, kernel, broadcom

I connected my Mac Mini to my network but every now and then the connection slows to almost zero without dropping.  I'm aware of and have followed some questions about similar issues on this site, however my question isn't about this.

In [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) which contains a great guide as the top voted answer a driver bcmwl-kernel-source is listed as the driver to install but not for my wireless card (which is Broadcom 4331).  I have installed the needed drivers for the 4331 (fwcutter and firmware-b43-installer) but the command "ubuntu-drivers devices" returns my wireless card 4331 and the driver is listed as bcmwl-kernel-source (distro non-free).  Does this mean fwcutter wasn't installed fully?  I'm not sure how to purge bcmwl-kernel-source since I didn't install it.  Or is this insignificant and the driver I installed is working properly?  Prior to fwcutter+installer I had no connection.

Additional:
It looks to me like bcmwl is preventing the drivers from running smoothly.  Theres a file in etc/modprobe.d blacklist-bcm43.conf blacklisting bcm43xx, bcma, b43 etc.  The file is autogened by bcmwl I've commented out bcm43xx but how can I (should I?) remove bcmwl?

I ran the commands suggested by @Jeremy31 and got the following results:
https://pastebin.com/MHWKRUV6

Results for   dpkg -l | grep -i broadcom   are::

```
    ii  b43-fwcutter   1:019-3   amd64   utility for extracting Broadcom 43xx firmware  

    ii  bcmwl-kernel-source   6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4   amd64   Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source
```

Comment: If you want to try using the firmware and the open source driver bcmwl needs to be removed

Comment: I've blacklisted bcmwl -is that what you mean?.

Comment: I get "the package isnt found".

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and edit the question to include the script results

Comment: @Jeremy31 added the results

Comment: I get >broadcom-sta-dkms isn't installed, so it can't be removed

Comment: What is result for `dpkg -l | grep -i broadcom`

Comment: @Jeremy31 I updated the answer with the results

Comment: `sudo apt remove bcmwl-kernel-source`

Comment: Uninstalled all dkms modules.  I rebooted.  grep result is the same

Comment: Try `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf && echo "blacklist wl" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` reboot

Comment: Did that, not sure what to check.  Is the STA driver removable?

Comment: Got it.  Ran remove --purge bcwl...source and that did it.  ubuntu-drivers devices still lists bcmwl-kernel-source as the driver after reboot.  Does that mean anything?  I found the command on this site

Comment: lspci returns the proper driver.  I'll see in a few days if the connection works better.

Comment: @Jeremy31 thank you, glad for your help